# Error when running rake db:seed using Faker gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, faker

I am trying to seed my seeds.rb file with the faker gem. I have faker in my gem file, I installed it. Here is my seeds.rb file:

```
require 'random_data'
require 'faker'

u = User.create(
  name: 'joe user',
  email: 'joe@user.com',
  password: 'password',
  confirmed_at: Time.now
)

15.times do
  User.create!(
  name: Faker::Name.name,
  email: Faker::Internet.email,
  password: Faker::Internet.password,
  #confirmed_at: Faker::DateTime.dateTime($max = 'now', $timezone =       date_default_timezone_get())
  confirmed_at: Time.now
  )
 end
users = User.all

  50.times do

  Wiki.create!(
  title:  Faker::Name.title,
  body:   Faker::Lorem.text($maxNbChars = 400),
  private: false,
  user: user.sample
  )
end
wikis = Wiki.all

puts "Seed finished"
puts "#{Wiki.count} wikis created"
puts "#{User.count} users created"
```

When I try to run `rake db:seed` I get this error:

`ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: index 'index_users_on_unlock_token': INSERT INTO "users" ("name", "email", "encrypted_password", "confirmed_at", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`

What is my issue?

Here is my schema.rb:It seems that there is a problem with index and users, email, confirmed_at, and created_at, since that is what the error is giving me.

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170817045146) do

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.integer  "role",                   default: 0
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
t.datetime "remember_created_at"
t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
t.string   "confirmation_token"
t.datetime "confirmed_at"
t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
t.string   "unconfirmed_email"
t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
t.string   "name"
  end

  add_index "users", ["confirmation_token"], name:     "index_users_on_confirmation_token", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  add_index "users", [nil], name: "index_users_on_unlock_token", unique: true

  create_table "wikis", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "title"
t.text     "body"
t.boolean  "private",    default: false
t.integer  "user_id"
t.datetime "created_at",                 null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",                 null: false
  end

  add_index "wikis", ["user_id"], name: "index_wikis_on_user_id"

end
```

Comment: Could you post the contents of your `schema.rb` file? Seems that there is a unique index on column `unlock_token` and you can't leave it empty.

Comment: editing now and adding the shame.rb

Comment: schema.rb file has been added

Answer (score 0):

As Magnuss pointed out, you have `unique` constraint on `unlock_token`. But according to the `schema.rb`, you have no `unlock_token` column for `Users`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort out your database schema. I'm not even sure how this works:

```
add_index "users", [nil], name: "index_users_on_unlock_token", unique: true
```

It's a bit hard to understand how you got to this database state, but if you don't actually have a column called `unlock_token` in your `users` table, I'd suggest creating a new migration and removing that unique index:

```
def up
  remove_index :index_users_on_unlock_token
end
```